Does TIA amplifier minimize the capacitance of a photodiode?
Let's say we have a photodiode modeled as follows where Cs represents PD capacitance:

We can say that, the larger the Cs the slower the response time of the photodiode.
Now we can use this photodiode in photovoltaic mode with a TIA amplifier as follows:

My confusion is:
In this case, the capacitor Cs is across the TIA's virtual ground and the ground which are at almost the same ground voltages. Does that mean the TIA is reducing the effective capacitance of the photodiode and speeding its response?
On the other hand, the input impedance of the TIA above is almost zero. This also makes the effective Rsh zero since now both Rsh and Cs are in parallel with a short(between virtual ground and ground). But this is very confusing.
But when I think these ways I'm super confused to proceed. How to clarify the input impedance and its effect on photodiode capacitance Cs and shunt resistor Rsh in a more didactic way. It seems I'm stuck with these thoughts, and cannot proceed with deductive arguments.
(images taken from https://www.analog.com/)


Does that mean the TIA is reducing the effective capacitance of the
photodiode and speeding its response?

The PD capacitance is still present so I prefer to think of the TIA as having a (near) zero input impedance and, that makes the RC time constant very low. Thus the main problem of the PD capacitance is neutralized.

If I want to again increase the RC time constant(to obtain a DC average response), can that be done by inserting a large the feedback capacitor?

All TIAs can benefit from feedback capacitance to optimize the noise but, there's nothing stopping you having a small resistor in series with the input to make the photodiode capacitor play more of a role in shaping the frequency response (with the added benefit of reducing noise gain) @cm64

I tried to add from 1 Ohm to 100k Ohm different resistor in simulation. But AC response and 3dB point didnt change much. I added resistor between PD model and the inverting input.  All I want is to lower the BW of the TIA with a variable resistor:((

Maybe you should add your simulation circuit to your question as a clear edit.

How about opening another question? I dont want to mess up this question by edits. People might like it.

sorry mistyped "might not like it" :))

Hi again. I opened a new question here. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/712293/how-to-modify-this-tia-amplifier-in-this-scenario Tried to be very explicit hope details are enough. Would be glad to hear your input.

Have you tried to use Analog Devices excellent interactive tool for TIAs. It does the business properly.

They are not for single supply and not for reducing the BW like in my case, I played with it. And confused with it. Even opened a question. I cannot get DIP opamps and dont understand how to use it for my averaging purpose. So it requires  more advanced knowledge. I gave up this TIA is super compilated in analyses.

Your simulator should deliver the goods

@cm64 if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Yes, the TIA speeds up the response, for exactly the reason you state. The cost is greater noise: the opamp amplifies its own input noise, and increased input capacitance increases the "noise gain". Also, the TIA circuit you've drawn is prone to instability: you generally need some capacitive feedback, too. That slows the response, but with careful attention to the phase margin the result can still be faster than it would be without the TIA.

I see, so if I want to make the TIA act as a low pass filter(to obtain a DC average response), should I just increase the feedback capacitor?

And if capacitance is nulled by feedback. Why would some circuits still need bias to reduce the capacitance?

@cm64 Reducing the capacitance of the detector reduces the noise gain of the TIA, for better signal/noise. Increasing the electric field in the depletion region sweeps charge out faster, potentially making the response faster. It also make the depletion region wider, improving quantum efficiency (still better signal/noise).

The current through a capacitor is \$i=C\frac
{dV}{dt}\$.  Note that the feedback amp keeps the voltage across the cap at zero, so the derivative is zero, and the current through the cap is zero.  Thus, all the current that comes from the photodiode must then go through the feedback resistor.
One way of describing this is indeed that the capacitance of the sensor has been nulled out.  Of course, a close look at the dynamics of the feedback loop is called for.

" and the current through the cap is zero. Thus, all the current that comes from the photodiode must then go through the feedback resistor." Can we say the same thing for Rsh? There's no potential difference across it? No current will pass through Rsh as well?

And if capacitance is nulled by feedback. Why would some circuits still need bias to reduce the capacitance?

@cm64 -- yes, the same can be said of Rsh, but for reasons that are a bit different -- that would be because there is no voltage drop across the resistor.  If an op-amp  TIA needs bias, it's usually because ground isn't an allowable input to a single-powered op amp unless it's rail-to-rail on the input.  The has nothing to do with nulling out the capacitance.
